# what is difference between hadoop and spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

As spark is growing in market nowadays I can see the Spark’s major use cases over Hadoop like:

1. Iterative Algorithms in Machine Learning
2. Interactive Data Mining and Data Processing
3. Spark is a fully Apache Hive-compatible data warehousing system that
   can run 100x faster than Hive.
4. Stream processing: Log processing and Fraud detection in live streams
   for alerts, aggregates and analysis
5. Sensor data processing: Where data is fetched and joined from
   multiple sources, in-memory dataset really helpful as they are easy
   and fast to process.

My question is:

1. Is spark going to replace Hadoop in upcoming days?
2. Hadoop work concurrently while spark runs in parallel?(is it true?)

Comment: Sorry, but it's a badly phrased question. What are you asking? The difference between Hadoop and Spark, or whether Spark is going to replace Hadoop? Or something about parallelism? (_Concurrent_ and _parallel_ mean the same thing.) Stack Overflow is not the right place for general _"Hey guys, what do you think about Spark?"_ type of discussion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spark differ from hadoop in the sense that let you integrate data ingestion, proccessing and real time analytics in one tool. Moreover spark map reduce framework differ from standard hadoop map reduce because in spark intermediate map reduce result are cached, and RDD(abstarction for a distributed collection that ii fault tollerant) can be saved in memory if there is the need to reuse the same results (iterative alghoritms, group by , etc etc).

My answer is really superficial and  does not not answer your question completly but just point out some of the main difference (much more in reality)
Spark and databricks  official site is really well documented and your question is already answered there :

https://databricks.com/spark/about

http://spark.apache.org/faq.html

Answer (score 5):

Hadoop today is a collection of technologies but in its essence it is a distributed file-system (HDFS) and a distributed resource manager (YARN). Spark is a distributed computational framework that is poised to replace Map/Reduce - another distributed computational framework that

1. used to be synonymous with Hadoop
2. ships with Hadoop out-of-the-box for backward compatibility (before YARN map/reduce support framework was Hadoop's resource management framework)

Specifically - Spark is not going to replace Hadoop but would probably replace map/reduce and Hadoop, map/reduce and spark are all distributed systems (and run in parallel)